# ROS Answers SE migration: pr2_cockpit

Tags: ros-diamondback, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I was wondering if pr2_cockpit is released in electric.
I was trying to use teleop_controllers package but it wasn't there in electric.
Should I stay in diamondback to use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11119/pr2_cockpit/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The JTTeleop controller is now located in robot_mechanism_controllers and it shows up in the controller manager as robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController.

---

Originally posted by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) with karma: 136 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1